# 'The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure to initialize the SDK by calling initialize_app()'

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, discord.py, roblox

I'm trying to make a python discord bot with the use of the Firebase Realtime Database for datastores. I'm initializing the app at the start of the script, however, when I try to create a reference I get the error `The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure to initialize the SDK by calling initialize_app()`. I don't know why this is happening since I initialized it?
Some code samples:

```
### I initialise the firebase app here?
# Variable def
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=">", help_command=None)
slash = SlashCommand(client, sync_commands=True)
token = os.environ['TOKEN']
BotGuilds = [916737523017986079]
cred_obj = firebase_admin.credentials.Certificate('rtdb-key.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred_obj, {
  'databaseURL':'https://datastoretuu-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/'
    }, f"main_bot")
```

```
### Cause of error
async def info(ctx: SlashContext, player: str=None):
  if player is None:
    player = ctx.author.nick


  tuu_logo = get(ctx.guild.emojis, name="tuu")
  pm_logo = get(ctx.guild.emojis, name="pm")
  roblox_logo = get(ctx.guild.emojis, name="roblox")
  discord_logo = get(ctx.guild.emojis, name="discord")

  apiresponse = requests.get(f"https://api.roblox.com/users/get-by-username?username={player}").json()
  playerid = apiresponse['Id']
  current_ref = db.reference(f"TUUPointStorage/{playerid}/Points")
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - Error is here
  result = current_ref.get()
```

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried without giving an application name? i.e. since you're giving a name (and there is no need for f-strings there), it won't be the default app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, if you give the application no name it will start working again. Thanks to MatsLindh for the answer.